# How to update Component link -> embedded Component field value using TOM.NET Event System

Tags: 2013-sp1, event-system, web8.5, tom.net

I would like to update an embedded Component field value when I check in my Page using TOM.NET Event System but the Component field value update is not happening.

I am not sure what am doing wrong here.

```
ItemFields componentFields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
if (componentFields.Contains("videoDetail"))
{
    EmbeddedSchemaField videoDetail = componentFields["videoDetail"] as EmbeddedSchemaField;
    if (videoDetail != null)
    {
        component.CheckOut();
        IList<ItemFields> videoDetailValues = videoDetail.Values;
        foreach (ItemFields innerFields in videoDetailValues)
        {
            if (innerFields.Contains("videoTitle"))
            {
                Headertext = innerFields["videoTitle"] as TextField;
            }
            if (innerFields.Contains("childPageName"))
            {
                XhtmlField childPageName = (XhtmlField)innerFields["childPageName"];
                childPageName.Value = component.Title;
            }
        }
    }
}
component.Content = componentFields.ToXml();
component.Save(true);
```

Comment: Can you confirm the foreach is being hit and that the conditions within them are hitting a true (i.e. via debugging). also (and I'm on a phone but).. looks to me like you're not actually updating the `innerFields` - can you write the debug value of the `innerFields.ToXml()` before you try to save?

Comment: Put Some Log in your code and trace it as @Dylan..MarkSaunders suggested. You are saving the component each and every time, is it required ? If not put it inside the condition. Also just for testing purpose try to check out the component before save and check in it after save. Let me know if it helps..

Comment: Thanks for the response. yes its going inside foreach and am getting component title value as expected but when I update the childPageName as component title it's not updating. Do I need to check out before update ?

Comment: Yes, a Component must be checked out before it can be modified, but I would expect the Save call to fail if the Component is not checked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too wasn't able to update the embedded Component field using `ItemFields` class; however, I was able to update it by XML node manipulation. Something like this should definitely work:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(component.Content.OuterXml);
var namespace = xDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

// Check if videoDetail embedded field exists
if (xDocument.Descendants(namespace + "videoDetail").Count() > 0)
{
    component.TryCheckOut();

    // Get videoDetail embedded field values
    var videoDetailValues = from videoDetail in
                            xDocument.Descendants(namespace + "videoDetail")
                            select videoDetail;

    foreach (XElement innerFields in videoDetailValues)
    {
        if (innerFields.Elements(namespace + "videoTitle").Any())
        {
            string headerText = innerFields.Elements(namespace +"videoTitle").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }

        // Set childPageName embedded field value to the title of the Component
        if (innerFields.Elements(namespace + "childPageName").Any())
        {
            innerFields.SetElementValue(namespace + "childPageName", component.Title);
        }
    }    
}

var updatedContent = new XmlDocument();
updatedContent.LoadXml(xDocument.ToString());
component.Content = updatedContent.DocumentElement;
component.Save(true);
```

May be experts here can answer as to how this can be achieved using `ItemFields` class. I've tested this by subscribing to a Page check-in event --
 `EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, CheckInEventArgs>(HandleForPageCheckInEvent, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);`

Comment: Thanks sabarish. I have implemented using XML node manipulation

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to save `innerFields` as Component content. But isn't `componentFields` actual content of Component?

Also, please make notice that you are trying to do this in Event System. This begs the question in which phase, and under which `EventArgs`.

It is possible that your Event System is not working correctly. If you want to debug Event System, you can do that "easily" [using this article.](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-made-easyish#more-2584)

Comment: yes your right it should be componentFields but still the component field is not updating. am trying remote event system debug.  here is the event system call.  EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<Page, CheckInEventArgs>(OnPageCheckInTransactionCommited, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);